# Repair boot partition

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

After updating the kernel, boot partition looks strange, here is `ls` output:

```
 root  /usr/src > ls -l /boot/
ls: cannot access '/boot/'$'\307\005''?'$'\021''H. B': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/boot/'$'\006'')?E'$'\020''.'$'\002\254\004': Input/output error
total 8541635
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   76613760 Apr  2  2052 ''$'\030''4'$'\001\307''H'$'\030\021''.'$'\f''*'$'\026'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2221816324 Nov 23  2016 '70A-V'$'\006''D..@6$'
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2312722265 Feb  9  2019 'ag?m'$'\025''h?".q'$'\342''?'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     112574 Oct 11 00:50  config-4.14.65-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     111211 Oct 11 00:11  config-4.14.65-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     121860 Jan 16 11:07  config-4.14.83-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     121860 Jan 16 10:41  config-4.14.83-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     122477 Feb  1 11:42  config-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     122477 Feb  1 11:31  config-4.18.13-gentoo.old
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  406883360 Dec 17  2092 ' '$'\004''D'$'\002\004''P'
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ''$'\006'')?E'$'\020''.'$'\002\254\004'
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root        512 Nov  2 09:34  EFI
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root       1024 Feb  1 11:44  grub
d????????? ? ?    ?             ?            ? ''$'\307\005''?'$'\021''H. B'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3955824 Oct 11 00:51  initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.65-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4104576 Jan 16 11:07  initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.14.83-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4112812 Feb  1 11:44  initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4060100 Nov  1 22:10  initramfs-gentest-x86_64-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7947120 Nov  1 22:09  kernel-gentest-x86_64-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        387 Oct 29 13:54  livecd-mount.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3630445658 Jan  1  2059 'si?_x?'$'\367\374''.'$'\341''0-'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3871048 Oct 11 00:50  System.map-4.14.65-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3579283 Oct 11 00:11  System.map-4.14.65-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3780712 Jan 16 11:07  System.map-4.14.83-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3780712 Jan 16 10:41  System.map-4.14.83-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3932691 Feb  1 11:42  System.map-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3936350 Feb  1 11:31  System.map-4.18.13-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3932456 Nov  1 22:09  System.map-gentest-x86_64-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    8003856 Oct 11 00:50  vmlinuz-4.14.65-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7205136 Oct 11 00:11  vmlinuz-4.14.65-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7639840 Jan 16 11:07  vmlinuz-4.14.83-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7639840 Jan 16 10:41  vmlinuz-4.14.83-gentoo.old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7947120 Feb  1 11:42  vmlinuz-4.18.13-gentoo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7967600 Feb  1 11:31  vmlinuz-4.18.13-gentoo.old
```

After update it contains strange files like in `ls` output above. When I try to delete these files I'm getting error that `boot` partition becomes read-only (I can remount it of course with `mount -o remount,rw /boot`, but after each `rm` command it becomes read-only again).

Boot partition is a grub2 usb stick with kernel images and luks keys. It's formatted as `fat32`, here's my `fstab` for `/boot`:

```
UUID=<my-uuid>      /boot       vfat        noatime,noauto      0 0
```

Is it possible to safely repair such boot partition without loosing all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `/boot` filesystem is corrupted.

In general, the `/boot` partition is not used while the system is running, other than for installing kernel and/or bootloader updates. So, it is quite possible to back up everything in it, and then unmount, completely destroy and then re-create the `/boot` filesystem. But obviously you should not reboot the system while doing so.

In this case, you should first back up all the valid-looking files from `/boot` and its sub-directories if you can.

Since your `/boot` partition is a USB stick, you should take another, known-good USB stick and start re-creating `/boot` on it. You can use `mkfs.vfat -i <VFAT uuid without separators>` to create a new filesystem with the same ID as the original.

Once complete, verify that it works (i.e. try booting with it). When you can successfully boot with the new stick, you can try running `fsck.vfat` on the original. If it fails, just wipe and re-create it. If it turns out the actual USB stick has developed a fault, destroy it physically and keep using your new one.

Consider maintaining two boot USB sticks, if not being locked out of your system is important to you. Remember that USB sticks can sometimes fail with no warning.